# React Router 6.4 not rendering component on page refresh or going directly to the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been messing around with React Router 6.4, but I'm having troubles with their new way of creating a routing system.

Here's the configuration:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/signin-redirect" element={<SignIn />} />
        </Route>
    )
);

const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
);
```

This works perfectly, if I go to localhost:9001 (which is the homepage) I see my `Home` component rendered inside of my `App` component.

I have a link inside of this `Home` component that goes to `/signin-redirect`

```
import React, { HTMLProps } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export interface Props extends HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {}

export const Home = ({ ...rest }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div {...rest}>
            <Link to="/signin-redirect">Sign in </Link>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Whenever I click on that link, it works perfectly. The page displays without any issues.

However, whenever I refresh the page or go to the page directly nothing gets rendered...

Comment: How are you running the app? What you describe sounds like you need to configure the server to redirect all page requests to the root index.html file. How this is done depends on the server environment. How are you serving the app currently?

Comment: It's a simple React application that gets run through webpack. Basically the same as CRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anybody in the future. In my webpack configuration I had a `devServer` option in which I had to add `historyApiFallback: true`.